# How do I replace values with the number in column header and combine across the entire row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transpose

I am trying to work on a function that has the following input:

```
   ID  Year  C01  C02  C03  C04  C05
0   1  2019    0    0    0    0    0
1   1  2020    1    0    0    0    1
2   2  2019    0    1    0    0    0
3   3  2020    0    0    0    0    0
4   4  2020    1    0    0    0    0
5   5  2020    0    0    1    0    0
```

I want to write a function that would return the following table:

```
   ID  Year   CC
0   1  2019     
1   1  2020  1,5
2   2  2019    2
3   3  2020     
4   4  2020    1
5   5  2020    3
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
new['C01'] = np.where(np.array(new['C01']==1),1,0)  
new['C02'] = np.where(np.array(new['C02']==1),2,0)  
new['C03'] = np.where(np.array(new['C03']==1),3,0)  
new['C04'] = np.where(np.array(new['C04']==1),4,0)  
new['C05'] = np.where(np.array(new['C05']==1),5,0)  
new['C06'] = np.where(np.array(new['C06']==1),6,0)  
new['C07'] = np.where(np.array(new['C07']==1),7,0)  
new['C08'] = np.where(np.array(new['C08']==1),8,0)  
new['C09'] = np.where(np.array(new['C09']==1),9,0)  
new['C10'] = np.where(np.array(new['C10']==1),10,0)
```

After this, I tried to use the dot join with row values which didn't work quite well.

I want to write a function that would do this and concat these values in a single column separated by a comma.

Comment: Okay, good luck with that.

Comment: Did you also mean to ask a question?

Comment: please share what have you tried. also if you were not able to come with solution, at least provide the input output format (csv file, multidimensional list, dictionary etc.)

Comment: Set the index to ['ID', 'Year'] then you can just `dot` with the columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793755/dataset-from-original

Comment: As an aside, are you trying to create a unique risk category for each individual-year based on their combination of HCC indicators? You could create this label with `groupy` + `ngroup` if you don't really care about whether the label is `'1,5'` or `17` so long as it's unique for a unique combination of indicators. (i.e. `df.groupby([x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('C')]).ngroup()`)

Comment: Let me explain the output table. For ID = 1 and year = 2020, The values are 1, 5 because columns CC01 and CC05 are marked as '1' in the input table. Similarly, for ID = 2, the value in the last column is 2 because CC02 = 1 for that particular row